# How to columnize text with tabs (in vim or on the shell)

Tags: vim, shell, text-editors

I have a frequent need to manually manipulate tab-delimited text for data entry and other purposes. When I do this, it helps if the text is aligned properly into columns. For example (assuming 4-space tabs):

```
# original format
abcdefghijklmnop    field2
abcdefgh    field2
abcdefghijkl    field2

# ideal format
abcdefghijklmnop    field2
abcdefgh            field2
abcdefghijkl        field2
```

I am very familiar with using the `column` utility to columnize text this way, but the problem is that it uses spaces to align the columns, and I specifically need tabs. This requirement also appears to rule out the Tabularize plug-in.

Is there any way that I can columnize text with tabs specifically, either within `vim` or at the shell? It looks like I might be able to do it with `groff`/`tbl`, but honestly I'd rather columnize it by hand than mess with that....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [csv.vim - A Filetype plugin for csv files](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=2830) also supports tab-delimited files, and has `:ArrangeColumn` and `:UnArrangeColumn` commands for that.

Comment: This actually sounds really promising. I will take a look and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: I haven't actually tried this yet, but i'm going to mark it as the accepted answer based on the documentation of the plug-in, and the fact that the only other useful answer was written by you anyway. Cheers.

Comment: If you want to change colors, the fg colors are hardcoded in macvim.

https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/blob/master/src/syntax.c#L7580-L7587

Comment: some sort of documented example of the syntax to use would help, since none exist on on the github page for that plugin.

Answer (score 10):

Set the tab display size to just larger than your longest field.

```
# original format
abcdefghijklmnop<Tab>field2
abcdefgh<Tab>field2
abcdefghijkl<Tab>field2
I have spaces!<Tab>field2
```

In Vim,

```
:echo len("abcdefghijklmnop") " Reports 16
:set noexpandtab tabstop=17
```

You can probably condense this to one command, but I don't know how. If you're running a modern Vim, `:set list` will indicate hard tabs with a fancy character (which you can also configure). Otherwise they'll just show as `^I` (not what you want) or whitespace.

```
# displays like this
abcdefghijklmnop>field2
abcdefgh>        field2
abcdefghijkl>    field2
I have spaces!>  field2
```

EDIT: [An example from a real running vim!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neo6I.png)

Answer (score 3):

Ideally you would like to use a command like

```
column -t -o '\t' file
```

But this doesn't work, since the `column` program does not escape the `\t` to interpret it like a `Tab`. But you can still insert a literal tab. To do so, press `Ctrl-V` and then the `Tab` key. So your command should be something like this:

```
column -t -o '        ' file
```

Where the big `'        '` is in fact a tab.

This works pretty neat. You can also run it inside vim. Visually select the lines you want to columnate, and then run:

```
:'<,'>!column -t -o '^I'
```

The `'<,'>` will automatically be written by vim, and the `'^I` is how vim will represent the literal tab, which you can insert with the method explained above.

Comment: `column -o $'\t'`
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html

Answer (score 1):

When you have properly space-aligned the table (with the mentioned *Tabularize* or the alternative *Align* plugin), you can then convert the spaces to tabs with the following commands:

```
:%retab!
:%substitute/ \+/\t/g
```

The first command replaces indent with tabs where possible without changing the widths (this assumes you've `:set noexpandtab`), the second then transforms the left-over spaces to (larger) tabstops.

Comment: I guess this will work, but only if i can be absolutely certain that there are no spaces within the fields themselves. Otherwise, i am not sure how it would be able to tell the difference between spaces within a field and the columnating ones left over by `:retab`. I will accept this answer if nobody has a more ideal solution.

Comment: The initial alignment wouldn't handle spaces within the fields, neither (but align on them, too). If you have such data, you'd probably have to substitute those inner spaces temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

Using [godlygeek/tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) plugin you can select

```
:%Tabularize /\t.*/
```

As mentioned by [@paul-rougieux](https://superuser.com/users/419414/paul-rougieux) in the comments we can abreviate the above command to:

```
:%Tab /\t.*/
```

Comment: You can abbreviate `:Tabularize` and call it like this `:Tab /\t` to align all tab separated text in the current buffer.

Answer (score -1):

Tab-separated columns only work when the program used to display them is able to expand/shrink tab characters to honor their actual meaning. Vim, and I believe most other plain text editors, is unable to use tabs for tabulation because tabs have a single fixed width. Vim can use a mix of tabs and spaces to obtain a roughly similar result but what you'd get is obviously not tab-separated anymore.

You'd need to convert all those tab/spaces mixes into single tabs on each write.

In short, a plain text editor is probably not the right tool for the job.

Comment: "tabs have a single fixed width"

Not true. See my answer. Many other editors have configurable tab size as wel.